# Automatically show Post chat feedback form after the chat ends

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent, livechattranscript

I want to display Feedback form automatically in the live chat window, once the User ends the chat. Currently, users need to click on the Feedback button to give feedback.
Current:

First Screen:

[image]

Second Screen:

[image]

Third Screen

[image]

Now instead of the third screen where user need to click on Give feedback button, I want to open a Feedback form automatically once user click on Confirm End Chat on the second screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Automatically open the post-chat feedback need to use below line:

```
embedded_svc.settings.autoOpenPostChat = true; // or false
```